# A closed-form for higher-order derivatives of the Dawson integral?

Tags: derivatives, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, hermite-polynomials

We have as the Dawson integral
$$
\mathcal D(x):=e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
I am interested in an expression for $\mathcal D^{(n)}(x)$ that does not involve sums.  For example, we could use the relation
$$
\mathcal D(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt\pi e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erfi}(x)
$$
to write
$$
\mathcal D^{(n)}(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt\pi \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} (\partial_x^ke^{-x^2})(\partial_x^{n-k}\operatorname{erfi}(x))
$$
and each of the remaining higher-order derivatives have closed-forms in terms of hypergeometric functions and hermite polynomials.  But can we write $\mathcal D^{(n)}(x)$ without sums?  My thought was to find a hypergeometric form for $\mathcal D(x)$ and then apply the well-known formulae for derivatives of hypergeometric functions to obtain the final result; however, I have not been able to find such a form of the Dawson integral. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, stranger ! Nice problem again. Cheers :-)

Comment: Can you access this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022407371901518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ClaudeLeibovici Provided reference to the paper *The derivatives of Dawson's function*  (Barakat,1971) found [here](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/0022-4073(71)90151-8). The paper gives the form
$$
\mathcal D^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n(H_n(x)\mathcal D(x)-G_{n-1}(x)),
$$
where $H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\partial_x^ne^{-x^2}$ is the $n$th degree Hermite polynomial and $G_n(t)$ is an $n$th degree polynomial satisfying
$$
G_n(x)=2xG_{n-1}(x)-2nG_{n-2}(x)
$$
with $G_0(x)=1$ and $G_1(x)=2x.$

Comment: Bingo and $\to +1$. Cheers, my friend.

Comment: Very satisfying answer.